# OneToMany with JoinColumn as PrimaryKey

Tags: jpa

Situation: A has a unidirectional OneToMany relation to B and B has a unidirectional ManyToOne relation to C:

A 1-->* B *-->1 C

In B I would like to have a compound primary key A.ID and C.ID, how do i have to modle this?

My main problem is, that the ID of A becomes the primary key in B.

Comment: You really should avoid composite PKs. Why don't you use an autogenerated, single-column primary key, as recommended?

Comment: I have to guarantee that the combination of A.ID and C.ID is unique - that's why I thought a composite PK makes sense - no?

Comment: Use a unique constraint. That's what they're for.

Comment: Ok but how can i make a unique constraint in B of a foreign key of A? In A I have following definition:

Entitiy A:
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_A", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private List<B> bs = new ArrayList<B>();

Comment: `fk_A` is a column of the table `B`. So you add a unique constraint in the table B, on `[fk_A, c_ID]`.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet - it's clear now.
I didn't realize that B can make a unique constraint on A's foreign key, as B has actually no control over it - so it seems to be a design by convention - I'm surprised, but ok.